# MongoDB User Authentication Fails In Node.js Script

Tags: node.js, mongodb

First, necessary preamble. I'm using MongoDB 4.0.0, and the mongoDB node.js driver version 3.1.1.

I'm trying to authenticate a user in my node.js script. Having successfully obtained a Db object corresponding to the admin database, I then use db.command() to perform the authentication. I create a command document, viz:

```
cmd = {
authenticate : 1,
user: g.UserName,
pwd: g.PassWord

}
```

and pass this command document to db.command(). The requisite variables specified above are, of course, defined, otherwise the code would halt with a ReferenceError.

When the db.command() executes my callback, the callback is presented with a MongoError object, containing the following:

```
{
code: 2,
codeName: "BadValue",
errmsg: "Auth mechanism not specified",
message: "Auth mechanism not specified",
name: "MongoError",
ok: 0
}
```

So, hunting through the documentation for MongoDB 4.0, I'm told that the authentication mechanism should be specified as "SCRAM", thus:

```
cmd = {
authenticate : 1,
user: g.UserName,
pwd: g.PassWord,
mechanism: "SCRAM"
}
```

When I supply the revised document to db.command(),the callback is presented with a different MongoError document:

```
{
code: 2,
codeName: "BadValue",
errmsg: "Unsupported mechanism: SCRAM",
message: "Unsupported mechanism: SCRAM",
name: "MongoError",
ok: 0
}
```

I then check in the Mongo shell, via the "show users" command, the data returned for the admin database, which consists of the following document:

```
{
    "_id" : "admin.Calilasseia",
    "user" : "Calilasseia",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
            {
                    "role" : "dbOwner",
                    "db" : "admin"
            }
    ],
    "mechanisms" : [
            "SCRAM-SHA-1",
            "SCRAM-SHA-256"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "admin.SuperUser",
    "user" : "SuperUser",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
            {
                    "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
                    "db" : "admin"
            }
    ],
    "mechanisms" : [
            "SCRAM-SHA-1",
            "SCRAM-SHA-256"
    ]
}
```

So at this point, I think, naturally, that specifying one of the listed mechanisms from the above document will solve the problem. Except that when I do this, the SAME MongoError document is sent to my callback.

Quite simply, my question is, why does this db.command() call not work? Why am I seeing this MongoError document every time I try to authenticate a user in my node.js code?

First of all, the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/method/db.auth/#db.auth) clearly states that the mechanism property of the cmd object I construct above is optional. From that page, we have:

> mechanism string  Optional. Specifies the authentication mechanism to use.
>
> For available mechanisms, see authentication mechanisms.
>
> If unspecified, uses the isMaster to determine the SASL mechanism or mechanisms for the specified user. See saslSupportedMechs.

Yet when I run the code, I am told that this entry is NOT optional, as above. Furthermore, supplying supposedly valid entries as specified in the documentation returns the second (annoying) MongoError document.

An explanation for this bizarre state of affairs would be welcome.

Comment: Extra weirdness: passing the SAME command document to db.auth() in the MongoDB shell WORKS. And works WITH OR WITHOUT the mechanism property in the command document object. At this point I would REALLY like to know why the node.js driver is falling over here ...

Comment: Extra weirdness 2: passing the command document to db.auth() in the MongoDB shell works, but passing that same command document to db.runCommand()  in the mongoDB shell FAILS in the exact same manner as for the node.js calls above.

Again, a situation in DIRE need of explaining.

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered this problem, it was a mismatch in versions between "mongo" (the mongo shell utility) and the mongo db server.